# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint DETAIL: Key already exists

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a server that delivers updates to devices using django.
This is my Model:

```
class updates(models.Model):
    name_device = models.CharField(max_length=200)#name of device
    number_ip = models.CharField(max_length=200)#number of ip
    name_update = models.CharField(max_length=200)#name of update
    date_send = models.CharField(max_length=200)#date of update
    status  = models.CharField(max_length=200)#status of update
```

Every time I call the function in code:

```
#The function creates a new update in the "updates_updates" table
def create(name_device,number_ip,name_update,date_send,status):
   updates.objects.create(name_device=name_device,number_ip=number_ip,
   name_update=name_update,date_send=date_send,status=status)
```

I get error every time on a different "**key**" for example:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "updates_updates_namedev_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name_device)=(car) already exists.
```

Comment: Did you provided correct model are you using any field that have `unique=True` or you have any relation in your models then provide that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help I was able to get in that I changed the type of columns to not be unique